# Xamarin.iOS build archiving error "Could not find a part of the path '.../Frameworks'"

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I am trying archive Xamarin.iOS build by press "Archive for Publishing" at Visual Studio for Mac. I get error `"Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(1431,3): error : Could not find a part of the path '/Users/[username]/Projects/[projectname]/[projectname]/[projectname]/[projectname].iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/[projectname].iOS.app/Frameworks'."`

What is wrong?

P.S. Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.1931, Xamarin.iOS 14.14.1.0

Comment: 1. Close visual studio and reopen and try
2. If not works, delete bin and obj from finder and close VS and try

Kind of issues used to get for VS. This may solve your issue.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't help.

Comment: Try to select [Link SDK assemblies only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=macos#link-sdk-assemblies-only).

Answer (score -1):

I have exactly the same problem: Rebuilding works perfectly with no errors but archiving iOS does not and shows the same error message.

I tried cleaning up the solution, removing bin folders and Mac cache, reinstalling the Apple certificates and provisioning profiles (no error there)... but I am still getting this exact issue.

Comment: Hey, I get you are new here so I want to let you know that this is not a proper answer but more a comment. Please, make sure the solution works for you before submitting it as an answer 